# Do neutrinos ever turn back to something less ghostly?

Tags: thermodynamics, neutrinos, weak-interaction

The most notable source of neutrinos seems to be the Sun. Obviously, the neutrinos are created from something else. Now as I think of it, they can just fly away through the solar system and be gone. This would indicate all matter is eventually going to turn to neutrinos.

So the question is whether neutrinos ever turn back to matter, by which I mean protons and neutrons right now, or is this how II. thermodynamic law decomposes bigger clumps of matter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, and indeed this was how the original [solar neutrino detection experiment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homestake_experiment) worked. It used the reaction:

$$ \nu_e + ^{37}\text{Cl} \rightarrow ^{37}\text{Ar} + e $$

The neutrino interacts with a neutron and turns it into a proton and electron.